# multiple configurations for sentry in same laravel app

Tags: php, laravel, cartalyst-sentry

How to get sentry to work with multiple models and tables in the same Laravel app? Something like this

model: **Member** - tables: **members** and **members_groups**

model: **Admin** - tables: **admins** and **admins_groups**

This is because I need different models with different column fields and methods.

I found some docs, but don't know exactly what is the best approach:

http://help.cartalyst.com/discussions/questions/110-how-to-use-multiple-configurations-of-sentry-in-the-same-laravel-4-app-one-for-public-and-one-for-admin-area

https://github.com/cartalyst/sentry/issues/190

https://github.com/cartalyst/sentry/issues/161

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## FOUND SOLUTION

I found a good solution and made a little how-to: https://gist.github.com/leabdalla/5999421